# Multiple condition calculated column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to figure out what's the best approach for this:

```
If C="WORD":

     A = 51 if B is between 0 and 2000
     A = 102 if B is between 2001 and 8000
     A = 204 if B is higher than 8000
     AND if D is ticked (checkbox) the A value turns into half`
```

I need this column to be "persisted", so that I can use it on reports.

For another column, I've used this and works:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.mytable 
    ADD C AS (A + B) / CASE D WHEN 1 THEN 4 ELSE 2 END;
```

Started with the this other code but it's not working and it still doesn't have the condition for the checkbox.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.tablename
    ADD FieldA AS (CASE 
                      WHEN FieldC = "Word"  
                         THEN
                            CASE 
                               WHEN FieldB > 0 AND FieldB < =2000 
                                  THEN 102
                               WHEN FieldB > 2000 AND FieldB <= 8000 
                                  THEN 204
                               WHEN FieldB > 8000 
                                  THEN 306
                               ELSE NULL         
                            END,
```

How can I proceed?

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have checkboxes, so it's not clear what you're actually trying to do here.   Is it maybe a `bit` field that can be either 0, 1 or NULL?

Comment: Yes, a bit column. Sorry, mixed the visual side with the sql side...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the short term, Tab is right about your typo.

In the bigger picture, you can save yourself some CPU time by taking advantage of the fact that `CASE` conditions are evaluated in order, so if you go backwards you only need to evaluate the last parameter. Also, by using the `POWER` trick, you'll dodge the `division by 0` error without having to introduce another `CASE` expression.

Alternative included if FieldD is a bit.

The values for `FieldA` vary between your problem statement and your code. I used the problem statement. Alter if needed.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.tablename
ADD FieldA AS 
  (
    CASE 
      WHEN FieldC = "Word" THEN
        CASE 
          WHEN FieldB > 8000 
            THEN 204
          WHEN FieldB > 2000
            THEN 102
          WHEN FieldB >= 0 
            THEN 51
          ELSE NULL
        END
    END
    / POWER(2,FieldD) --<--- Or, possibly, POWER(2,CAST(FieldD AS tinyint))
   )
```

Comment: I'm testing it and keep getting the error "Incorrect syntax near ')'."
Instead of copy paste I wrote the code, I even used it on Notepad++ and played a little with the encoding, but keep getting the same error...

Comment: Yup, you sure are. :) I wrote it off the top of my head in Notepad++ myself. Sorry about that. I, too, had the last END in the wrong place. Edited the post.

Comment: Thank you for you help! I will test it further but it seems to be working, even when I change the values of the field after the first input.

Comment: or anyone available to help me out, what if Field C has 2 more options that return "0"? (or even if nothing is selected)
Would this be correct?

ALTER TABLE dbo.tablename
ADD FieldA AS 
  (
    CASE 
      WHEN FieldC = "Word" THEN
        CASE 
          WHEN FieldB > 8000 
            THEN 204
          WHEN FieldB > 2000
            THEN 102
          WHEN FieldB >= 0 
            THEN 51
          ELSE NULL
        END
       ELSE "0"
    END
    / POWER(2,FieldD) --<--- Or, possibly, POWER(2,CAST(FieldD AS tinyint))
   )

Answer (score 3):

Your attempt "isn't working" because you have two `CASE` expressions and only one `END`.   You need an `END` for each `CASE`.

Comment: And a closing `)` since there's an opening `(` without it being closed ...

Comment: Kept looking at it over and over and never noticed that! *Shy*

Answer (score 0):

Hope this would work:

```
        ALTER TABLE dbo.tablename
        ADD FieldA AS (CASE   WHEN FieldC = "Word" and (FieldB>0 AND FieldB<=2000) THEN 51
                              WHEN FieldC = "Word" and (FieldB>2000 AND FieldB<=8000) THEN 102
                              WHEN FieldC = "Word" and (FieldB>8000 ) THEN 204
                         ELSE NULL         
                         END    
                        )
```

Comment: It works :) Just misses the bit column stuff. The condition of the "D" field that turns "A" value in its half